# Adding Destination in Hana Cloud Platform

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I have a HANA cloud Platform account. When I create a SAPUI5 Application in web-ide, I do not see the services(xsodata) that I developed in web-based development workbench.

Is it because the host changes for each service provided through the cockpit i.e.

for HANA services, it is:

```
<schemaName><accountname>.hanatrial.ondemand.com
```

and for web-ide:

```
webide-<accountname>.dispatcher.hanatrial.ondemand.com
```

Should we be creating destinations every time we want to consume a service developed in HCP itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, that's right. You need a `destination` in order to be able to access your services, whether it is a XSOData service, or any other service for that matter.

Do keep an eye on the `Additional Properties` of your destination. If you don't set them, you still won't be able to use the destination from WebIDE.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a document describing the meaning of each additional property that is required or can be added when creating a destination?

Comment: @Deepak Yes, there is: https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide/frameset.htm?5c3debce758a470e8342161457fd6f70.html